# Why does the Gyro Sensor not work correctly in Virtual Robotics Toolkit?

Tags: ev3, software

I somehow found out about Virtual Robotics Toolkit and when I did, I decided that it would be great software to use for Lego League. Later in my research, I found that it automatically had the newest tables.

Soon I was designing a robot and code for my team, but as soon as I tested it the virtual robot started driving off to one side. Even though it was doing this, the EV3 software said that it was at 0°. When I tested the same program in real life, the robot drove perfectly straight.

[image: The virtual robot drives off to one side]

You can download the source code here. ([ORBIT3R-BOT.ev3](https://mega.nz/#!DjhghQrb!kfSFt6dHQigdXHszw2cVrnC7uS0UIcTI9PYSKLuZzQw))
You can download the robot model here. ([ORBIT3R-BOT.lxf](https://mega.nz/#!7u42RKLC!mM-cZ3SXXboVbWbkc3WWPu8VpSp-X8Dxr5TJ2YOWKGg))
You can download the robot model here. ([ORBIT3R-BOT.ldr](https://mega.nz/#!vnhCDawa!XBXN_GooS5mi21VapMKikpS_FlfDscRR7JwxGuunKyU))
You can download the VRT project here. ([IntoOrbit](https://mega.nz/#F!WqhQSKpB!PrxnSHlHCLlVv09vsZftNQ))
You can download all the above (and more) here. ([Robot](https://mega.nz/#F!Syg2wQaQ!lk6OQqTUR-d7y7NFcy3AXA))

Answer (score -1):

Try to reset angle on the gyro sensor. Click on the block and choose reset.

Comment: I have already tried that.